# Databricks $ inside of the name column returs mistake with a command

Tags: sql, databricks

```
select from_unixtime(date.$date/1000) as date from blabla
```

I have a code like above with the problem that I always get an error cause of $ in a name of the object $date. How can I avoid it?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
select table.date::struct<`$date`: bigint>.`$date` as date from table
```